# Bootstrap slider does not work when setting images in table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, indexing, slider, position

First problem is a Bootstrap slider: I try to slide iframes when user clicking at the image and its work, but not when I set images in a HTML table.

Second: is a multiple refreshing page, I think the reason is in iframes because when I changing iframes to images problem disappears. Anybody knows what is wrong?

My HTML code:

```html
<div class = "content">         
 <div class = "icons"> 
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <a href="johnMaus" class="link" rel="1" > <img 
     src="image/icons/disabled/JohnMaus.jpg" height="200px"
     id='JohnMaus'class="imgIcon"/></a>
    </td>
    <td>
     <a href="JimiTenor" class="link" rel="2"> <img  
     src="image/icons/disabled/JimiTenor.jpg" height="200px"
     id='JimiTenor' class="imgIcon" /></a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>                                                       
 <div  class="carousel" style="display:none">
  <div class="container" style="width:550px">
   <div class="well span9 columns">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <div class="carousel-inner" style="text-align:center">
      <div class="item active">
       <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/52jWkrfjakk" 
        frameborder="0"></iframe>             
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/52jWkrfjakk"
       frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>                                                                                    
     </div> 
     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><img 
     src="image/Buttons/prev.jpg" id="leftbtn"/></a>
     <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><img   
     src="image/Buttons/next.jpg" id="rightbtn"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>              
 </div>
 <div class="description">
  <div class="desc">
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  And javascript code:

   //pause slider
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(
    {
        pause: true,
        interval: false
    });
   // slide to specific position
    $('.link').on('click', function()           
     {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel($(this).index());
    });
    // show slider
    $( ".link" ).click(function() 
    {
        $( ".carousel" ).show( "slow" );
    });

// load video description
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    $('.link').click(function()
    {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.desc').load('desc/'+ page +'.txt');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your problem is, as [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJzJB/) seems to be working fine with tables. You should still

- only invoke `.click()` resp. `.on('click')`(they mean the same) once
- call any function regarding DOM elements after the document is ready (`$(document.ready()`)
- definitly call `event.preventDefault()` on the event given to the function you put in the argument of `.click()`
- load

And `.carousel()` does not take booleans for `pause` or `interval`. You'll find more and detailed information in the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: thans for the answer, but I find problem, its mean  $('#myCarousel').carousel($(this).index()) change to  $('#myCarousel').carousel($(this).parent().index());